# Return data for first key stroke undefined in jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to implement jQuery autocomplete using the approach illustrated below (i.e. a separate source function and an intermediary variable for the data). Right now I'm trying to get the data to the source part of the autoComplete function.

The code below works with one fatal issue, the very first key stroke returns an undefined `returnData` variable. Can any one explain what's going on?

```
var returnData;
function sourceFn() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: //REST URL,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        async: false,
        data: {
            featureClass: "P",
            style: "full",
            maxRows: 12,
            name_startsWith: request.term
        },
        success: function (data) {
            returnData = data;
        },
    })
}
}

$("input#search-input").bind("autocompleteselect", jQuery.proxy(function (event, ui) {}, this)).autocomplete({
    appendTo: "#yt-result-list",
    source: function (request, response) {
        sourceFn(request, response).done(alert("returnData: " + JSON.stringify(returnData)));

    }
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = jQuery.proxy(function (ul, item) {
    alert(item);
}, this)

});
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifing the `minLength: 0` when initializing the autocomplete, check the value of returnData to see if you get the json back from the server (use firebug).
Looks like you're not getting from the ajax call with one letter only, the autocomplete is triggering `sourceFn()` correctly.

Comment: minLength: 0 didn't do it. I am geting good data in the AJAX success function on one key stroke, but it's triggering after sourceFn(request, response).done().

Comment: returnData is assigned from the ajax call, if it's undefined on the first stroke there's the chance you're not getting any data. Place an alert on the onsuccess of the ajax call.